# Using a string as a component name in react and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I have an input component that can either render a textarea component (from a library) or a regular input.
This is the component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import './AppInput.css'

interface Props {
    placeholder: string,
    value: string | number,
    setValue: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>,
    text: string,
    shouldFocusOnKey: boolean,
    type: string,
    name: string,
    className: string,
    Component: string
}

export const AppInput: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
    const { 
        placeholder, 
        value, 
        setValue, 
        text, 
        shouldFocusOnKey, 
        type = 'text', 
        name, 
        className, 
        Component='input' } = props
    let inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (shouldFocusOnKey) {
            window.onkeydown = (e) => {
                if (e.ctrlKey && e.key === 'm') {
                     inputRef.current?.focus()
                }
            }
        }
    }, [shouldFocusOnKey])

    return (
        <div className={`appinput ${className}`}>
            <span>{text}</span>
            <div className="flexcol">
                <Component 
                    ref={inputRef} 
                    placeholder={placeholder} 
                    value={value} 
                    onChange={(e) => { 
                        setValue(e.target.value)
                    }} 
                    type={type} 
                    name={name} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

In the case that Component === 'ReactTextareaAutosize'
Then I want to render that component as depicted.This works perfectly well in ReactJS. But when using ReactTS I get type errors etc as typescript does not understand what I am trying to do or doing.
Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: You can check my answer, try use component name you want use (it just string, in my case, it was `div`), and use className (string) which you want to use instead of my example. In my case I needed to generate className string for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [createElement](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/createElement#createelement)

Here is example that used in my code:
[image: Code Sample]

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `useRef` type, simply resolve the actual component from the value of your `Component` prop, so that it is no longer a simple `string`, but either an `input` or an actual `ReactTextareaAutosize` React Component:

```
import ReactTextareaAutosize from 'react-textarea-autosize'

interface Props {
    // other props
    Component: 'input' | 'ReactTextareaAutosize'
}

export const AppInput: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
    const {
        // other props
        Component = 'input' } = props

    const ActualComponent = Component === 'ReactTextareaAutosize' ? ReactTextareaAutosize : Component

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="flexcol">
                <ActualComponent />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgKIBmZSG2RSyZNxAyjCjEnAL5xlQQhwA5FFQZBAKFCRYiUTAAqSAB6sRKAIL4YEQsABeHXvyFqMAWnYqUasyi079SCZIB27KGXQcACnzCFccThguDAAGy8ACwgwgBMkKAAuOEIYKGAXAHNMIJCANxQw-CRk1PSsuAAfOBd8EAAjBJyQlKQYADVC4uTkdBgAOgARYEIwNjRIgB5ejH6mNpY2JHUMYAgXSbKMzIA+HeaQyxhStO2D4MJo-DiAMQg0IgB5FwBpJABPZPqIGNQXc7gMHeYBKKVOWQBLhQIFBWwhuWCaAihEIADlobDwdkEXAAML8SAuJBuZKCDJgLSCKpCGYKZSqVCabS6AwSTjicTKaTwNDrVJwdRgMAASRcFOOsj6-RuuMmvgg-h2cAAvHAABRgPyEACUKqVOBxvJc-INLRa4SiMXiUABLQKRSQtpCxA6XUdOJaRydFyut3uT1eH29gOBHFVgiOgmDUJhwaRKBR6NjHpC+PA62J8HD5MpXBVoS1OLCbTgOZg9HztHokwAEvIALIAGVF4pIxZhbmpdabihU6jUbaQHZgOzVtTCYW1HJaRv5Kxg+EKacJmfzy4zneVW5pcl7DI09hZTjgAH5JRg99ZGYfHHBkuuiW4cQB6Z9m98fgB6J+nIVo5EoDA1TVXVlX1FNgmAMh1UuCBrliO4HkIZ43neXVTQ-FoAHcMliCAsP6dYAGsPjwrCXHzNUkFA8DMMwqD1SQfoMCgMJULgAAyDi4CYkj3hVbdBBAQR0IguiWjLehmPwKARDcE9+jIf1CBAsTMPZcTgg0j9tK07AAG1YPgxCA1QgBdKccREBcoAotUxMmWJgDyOB40TDFlRwAADFAhTLOAABIcDctEMU4LzOB2NSQk2MYXB2HAjk4SZn1GFB4ui4JHOc1zkVCmFlQAIjIYslF5MJCqizSzUmedFzCB9M0yuiRDITzJKQMhdOqs0LTQJBojiBJPL6garQSbqevyN1PPtYpJqmuB1lxSJ0syJBPKomjAkWuiXU6B0qP6VR1oGObqOa9SFqmoEQU826kGunqYw2nAXu4Z8qs0lKnLyL73x+5z-rgKd2SAA)

---

As for the `useRef` type, if you just need for simple usage like `.focus()`, i.e. common properties/methods of `<input>` and `<textarea>`, then the easiest would be to type it as the intersection `HTMLInputElement & HTMLTextAreaElement`, so that it is compatible with both elements, and you can use all common properties/methods:

```
const inputRef = useRef<
  HTMLInputElement & HTMLTextAreaElement
>(null)

inputRef.current?.focus() // Okay

<ActualComponent
  ref={inputRef} // Okay
/>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgKIBmZSG2RSyZNxAyjCjEnAL5xlQQhwA5FFQZBAKFCRYiUTAAqSAB6sRKAIL4YEQsABeHXvyFqMAWnYqUasyi079SCZIB27KGXQcACnzCFccThguDAAGy8ACwgwgBMkKAAuOEIYKGAXAHNMIJCANxQw-CRk1PSsuAAfOBd8EAAjBJyQlKQYADVC4uTkdBgAOgARYEIwNjRIgB5ejH6mNpY2JHUMYAgXSbKMzIA+HeaQyxhStO2D4MJo-DiAMQg0IgB5FwBpJABPZPqIGNQXc7gMHeYBKKVOWQBLhQIFBWwhuWCaAihEIADlobDwdkEXAAML8SAuJBuZKCDJgLSCKpCGYKZSqVCabS6AwSTjicTKaTwNDrVJwdRgMAASRcFOOsj6-RuuMmvgg-h2cAAvHAABRgPyEACUKqVOBxvJc-INLRa4SiMXiUABLQKRSQtpCxA6XUdOJaRydFyut3uT1eH29gOBHFVgiOgmDUJhwaRKBR6NjHpC+PA62J8HD5MpXBVoS1OLCbTgOZg9HztHokwAEvIALIAGVF4pIxZhbjgADI4HWm4oVOo1G2kB2YDs1bUwmFtRyWkb+SsYPhCmnCZn82uM53lbuaXIBwyNPYWU44AB+SUYQ-WRknxxwZJboluHEAejfZq-34Aeue5yEtDkJQGBqmqurKvqKbBMAZDqpcEDXLEdwPIQzxvO8uqmt+LQAO4ZLEEC4f06wANYfIRuEuPmapIBBUE4ThsHqkg-QYFAYQYd2PaseR7wqnugggIIWHQYxLRlvQbH4FAIhuOe-RkP6hDgXAH5wI8pEoO8Yk4ey4nBPp35GYZ2AANoIUhKEBhhAC6s44iIy5QNRapiZMsTAHkcDxomGLKjgAAGKBCmWcAACQ4L5aIYpwgWcDsukhJsYwuDsOBHJwkxvqMKBpUlwQeV5PnIjFMLKgARGQxZKLyYQVYlBlmpMS4rmEz6ZgVjEiGQAWSUgZDcOpmnaV1OEWmgSDRHECQBRNU1WgkJlNWa9rFAFa1IMtK0hOsuKRHlmRIAFtH0YEO3iS6nQOrR-SqEdAybbOF1mpw20XUCIIBZ9W1jd+MbHTgANDY1BnZZ5eSg1+4NeVDcCzuyQA)

---

Now if you absolutely need to be able to use specific properties and/or methods to `<input>` and `<textarea>` elements, then things get more verbose just for the sake of safe typing unfortunately.

The most straightforward technique is to separate the `ref` and actual component for each possibility:

```
const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)
const textareaRef = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>(null)

inputRef.current?.focus() // Okay
textareaRef.current?.focus() // Okay

<div className="flexcol">
  {Component === 'input'
    ? <input
        ref={inputRef} // Okay
      />
    : <ReactTextareaAutosize
        ref={textareaRef} // Okay
      />
  }
</div>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgKIBmZSG2RSyZNxAyjCjEnAL5xlQQhwA5FFQZBAKFCRYiUTAAqSAB6sRKAIL4YEQsABeHXvyFqMAWnYqUasyi079SCZIB27KGXQcACnzCFccThguDAAGy8ACwgwgBMkKAAuOEIYKGAXAHNMIJCANxQw-CRk1PSsuAAfOBd8EAAjBJyQlKQYADVC4uTkdBgAOgARYEIwNjRIgB5ejH6mNpY2JHUMYAgXSbKMzIA+HeaQyxhStO2D4MJo-DiAMQg0IgB5FwBpJABPZPqIGNQXc7gMHeYBKKVOWQBLhQIFBWwhuWCaAihEIADlobDwdkEXAAML8SAuJBuZKCDJgLSCKpCGYKZSqVCabS6AwSTjicTKaTwNDrVJwdRgMAASRcFPgAF44AAKMB+QjJXwQfwASjgEp2gRavJc-JwOJa4SiMXiUABLQKRSQ5pCxA6XWtBsO9JtFyut3uT1eH1dgOBHClgiOgl9UJhvqRKBR6PDTuC+PA62JkqE5MpXHVoXlOLCbTgaZg9EztHokwAEvIALIAGVF4pIuZhbh20tqYTCKpzeaO1lQRalJaQZHLVerihU6jUDaQTZgLbbHY5LVo5EoGGl0rVGq1LRCwDIMsuEGusTuD0Izze7zV+t3d7gAHcMrEIA-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-jjmeepeQXXeXlMyzcCduyQA)